# getAxis method returns CTCallCenter instance

Tags: ios-charts, carthage

I started to use `Charts.framework`.

I tried to set `axisMinimum` of an instance of `YAxis` that is gotten by `getAxis` method, but got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

The reason was that the instance was an instance of **CTCallCenter**, not YAxis.
I believe that this is my configuration mistake to put Charts.framework into my project, but I have no idea what is wrong.

What I did were,

1. installed Carts.framework by Carthage.
2. added the framework into "Linked frameworks and Libraies in General of project setting.
3. added "Run Script" of "/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks" in Build Phases.
4. added the framework into "Copy Files" in Build Phases.

Is there anyone who experienced the same problem?
Could you give me any advices to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a problem of either Charts or Carthage.
It is my mistake about Storyboard.

I specified Class as a class of Charts but forgot to specify Module in Main.storyboard.